# Where is the documentation for net.ipv4.conf.all.log_martians?

Tags: linux, man, documentation

Where is the documentation for `net.ipv4.conf.all.log_martians` sysctl setting? There are man pages for various other TCP/IP/UDP (`man 7 tcp`, `man 7 upd`, `man 7 ip`) settings, but I can't find the `net.ipv4.conf.all.log_martians` docs.

Note: I want official documentation from Linux; not random sites from google.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Things you find in the man pages are generally about programming, and the C API. Non-programming documentation is generally found in the kernel itself.

https://git.kernel.org/cgit/linux/kernel/git/torvalds/linux.git/tree/Documentation/networking/ip-sysctl.txt?id=bb077d600689dbf9305758efed1e16775db1c84c#n843

And those random google sites aren't usually wrong. I'm sure you'll find that many of them are just online versions of the kernel documentation.